# Deployment with tomcat7 manager, change directory for uploaded war

Tags: tomcat

I am fighting with .war deployments using tomcat manager, it is starting webapp twice because I have defined hosts under server.xml. So it deployes one app for example.com and other one for /example.

As far as I know only way how to deal with that is to place my .war outside webapps folder, but is there any possibility to specify directory from which to run my war when deploying?

```
        <Host name="myapp.com" appBase="/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/myapp" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
            <Context path="" docBase="."/>
        </Host>

        <Host name="deploy.myapp.com" appBase="/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/manager" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
            <Context path="" docBase="."/>
        </Host>
    </Engine>
```

Comment: You need to include more of your configuration.  We'll need to see what's in server.xml.  Double deployments generally indicate a configuration problem.  Also, if you could clarify the exact steps to replicate the problem that would be helpful.

Comment: Well, I added configuration. But as I wrote basically problem is that app is deployed twice - once for manager and then for the host specified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the docs...

> When using automatic deployment, the docBase defined by an XML Context file should be outside of the appBase directory.

You're setting *docBase* to ".", which is not outside of the *appBase* directory.  This is not good and can cause double deployments.  There's a handful of ways you can fix this.

1.) Restructure the folders under "/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps" so that there are "myapp.com" and "deploy.myapp.com" sub directories.  Then change the *appBase* for each *Host* tag so that it points to the appropriate sub directory.  With that in place remove the *Context* tag, which is not recommended in *server.xml* anyway, and simply rename the "myapp" subdirectory to "ROOT" (exactly like that, case is important).  Do the same for "manager", rename it "ROOT".

That'll give you a structure like this:

`/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/myapp.com/ROOT
/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/deploy.myapp.com/ROOT`

The net result is that you'll have two hosts, each host with one app deployed as the ROOT application (i.e. /).

2.) Continue with things as they are but set *autoDeploy* to *false*.  You're defining the contexts directly in *server.xml*, so you don't need *autoDeploy*.  In fact, disabling it should get rid of the double deployments.

A slight alteration to this approach would be to lead *autoDeploy* as true but use the *deployIgnore* attribute so that Tomcat's auto deployment skips the apps you've manually configured with contexts in server.xml.

I'd recommend option #1 as it's the cleanest approach.

Comment: Great, 1st helped me! But what about manager, how do I deploy myapp.com? I need to specify path, and if I do that it is deployed under deploy.myapp.com/<path>

Comment: I don't think that will actually work.  As far as I know, the Manager app doesn't give you the ability to set the host where it'll deploy stuff.  It seems to assume the same host where it's running.  What you might try is running manager in the same host as your app, then push an app to deploy.myapp.com with just the [UrlRewriteFilter](http://tuckey.org/urlrewrite/).  That can then rewrite deploy.myapp.com to go to myapp.com/manager (google "urlrewritefilter cross context forward" for more on that).